# do the in statement iterates over a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, time-complexity

Say I have the following dictionary:

```
mydict = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
}
```

are these the same in complexity?

```
return mydict.get("a", None) is not None
return "a" in mydict
```

I assume they still need to iterate over the dictionary, since if I want to look for key: "d", I would need to check all keys whether it exists or not, so both operations are O(n).

a follow up question is, does the same apply for lists? Say I have:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

does

```
5 in mylist
```

also iterates over the whole list to find the number? I am asking because I saw this leetcode answer: https://www.code-recipe.com/post/two-sum in which 2 nested for loops is not preferred, but a for loop, and an `in` check, is way faster, but to me it sounds like both are doing nested loops.

Comment: Dictionaries don't need to iterate over all keys to get the value in general. Look up how hash tables work.

Comment: [Time Complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Answer (score 0):

```
return mydict.get("a", None) is not None
return "a" in mydict
```

Technically speaking, checking wether a key exists or not in a dictionnary is constant time O(1), because of how Hash works, you directly know wether the key exists or not

Now if you want to be precise, `mydict.get("a", None) is not None` is a tad slower than `"a" in mydict`

Because for the first one you verify if the key is in the dictionnary, then you return either the key or None, and then verify the equality, while in the 2nd one, you just verify if the key is in the dictionnary or not

It might seem like not much, but on very big data it can make a difference since comparison is slow in CPython

Comment: `is not` is not the full rich comparison machinery you're likely thinking of when you say "comparison is slow in CPython". `is not` is implemented as a simple pointer equality check (since it's an identity comparison, not a value comparison). Calling `.get` is a titch slower (mostly due to `.get` following generic function call paths rather than an optimized path directly to the containment check code), and the `is not None` is *technically* contributing, but we're talking 5 ns, give or take, on my machine (using `!= None` would bump the cost to ~20 ns).

Comment: Also, if you're going to use "Technically speaking", you can't say `dict` membership testing is `O(1)`. It's *average/expected case* `O(1)`, but in pathological conditions (every key in the `dict` has the same hash code, or at least a hash code which collides modulo the number of buckets) it can rise to `O(n)`. Really, the big problem with `mydict.get("a", None) is not None` is that it will tell you a key is not in the `dict` if the key *is* in the `dict`, but happens to map to `None`.

Comment: Pedantic correction to my own correction: `!= None` bumps it up to ~20 ns on my machine when using a built-in type. The cost would go higher for user-defined types which override `__eq__`/`__ne__`. But `is not` stays constant no matter what (it never calls any Python code).